# PHP function putting incorrect <ul><li> in tree hierarchy

Tags: php, html, tree

I am using this function to display UL list:

```
function getList($arResult){
    $diff = 0;
    foreach($arResult as $result){
        if($lastlevel != $result[depth]){
        if($lastlevel < $result[depth]){
            $html .= "<ul>\n";
            $diff++;
        }
        else {
            $html .= "</li>\n</ul>\n</li>\n";
            $diff--;
        }       
        }
        else
        $html .= "</li>\n";

        $html .= "<li>$result[cat_name]";

        $lastlevel = $result[depth];
    }
    $html .= str_repeat("</li>\n</ul>\n", $diff);
    return $html;
    }
```

The `$arResult` contains a tree like this:

```
Electronics
  TV
  Video
    Old Movies
    New Movies
    Hollywood
      Old hollywood
      New HollyWood
      Rotten Hollywood
    Other Movies
  Mobile
    Nokia
    Apple
    Micromax
  Laptop
  Other
```

The above function prints everything under `Electronics->Tv` while the truth is that under `Electronics` there should be `TV, Video, Mobile Laptop, Other` ..

This function somehow is putting `ul li` in incorrect mode.

The Array Dump is here:

```
array(10) {
  [0]=>
  array(6) {
    ["cat_ID"]=>
    string(3) "197"
    ["cat_name"]=>
    string(13) "Student Corner"
    ["cat_nicename"]=>
    string(13) "student-corder"
    ["parent"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["post_count"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["depth"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(6) {
    ["cat_ID"]=>
    string(3) "198"
    ["cat_name"]=>
    string(6) "GujCET"
    ["cat_nicename"]=>
    string(13) "gujcet-gujrat"
    ["parent"]=>
    string(3) "197"
    ["post_count"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["depth"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(6) {
    ["cat_ID"]=>
    string(3) "199"
    ["cat_name"]=>
    string(13) "Sample Papers"
    ["cat_nicename"]=>
    string(20) "sample-papers-gujcet"
    ["parent"]=>
    string(3) "198"
    ["post_count"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["depth"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(6) {
    ["cat_ID"]=>
    string(3) "200"
    ["cat_name"]=>
    string(8) "Syllabus"
    ["cat_nicename"]=>
    string(15) "syllabus-gujcet"
    ["parent"]=>
    string(3) "198"
    ["post_count"]=>
    string(1) "8"
    ["depth"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(6) {
    ["cat_ID"]=>
    string(3) "201"
    ["cat_name"]=>
    string(4) "News"
    ["cat_nicename"]=>
    string(11) "news-gujrat"
    ["parent"]=>
    string(3) "197"
    ["post_count"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["depth"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(6) {
    ["cat_ID"]=>
    string(3) "202"
    ["cat_name"]=>
    string(13) "Question Bank"
    ["cat_nicename"]=>
    string(20) "question-bank-gujrat"
    ["parent"]=>
    string(3) "197"
    ["post_count"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["depth"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(6) {
    ["cat_ID"]=>
    string(3) "203"
    ["cat_name"]=>
    string(7) "Class X"
    ["cat_nicename"]=>
    string(28) "class-x-gujrat-question-bank"
    ["parent"]=>
    string(3) "202"
    ["post_count"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["depth"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [7]=>
  array(6) {
    ["cat_ID"]=>
    string(3) "204"
    ["cat_name"]=>
    string(9) "Class XII"
    ["cat_nicename"]=>
    string(30) "class-xii-gujrat-question-bank"
    ["parent"]=>
    string(3) "202"
    ["post_count"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["depth"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [8]=>
  array(6) {
    ["cat_ID"]=>
    string(3) "205"
    ["cat_name"]=>
    string(7) "Results"
    ["cat_nicename"]=>
    string(15) "results-gujarat"
    ["parent"]=>
    string(3) "197"
    ["post_count"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["depth"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [9]=>
  array(6) {
    ["cat_ID"]=>
    string(3) "206"
    ["cat_name"]=>
    string(10) "About GSEB"
    ["cat_nicename"]=>
    string(10) "about-gseb"
    ["parent"]=>
    string(3) "197"
    ["post_count"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["depth"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}
```

Comment: What is "incorrect mode"? Please clarify, and add the output to the post!

Also, correct indentation would help quite some when understanding your code...

Comment: What does your array look like ??? `var_dump($arResult)`

Comment: Array dump is posted.. please tale a look @ppeterka

Comment: Array dump is posted please take a look @Baba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Way too complicated a function. Something along these lines does it:

```
function treeList(array $data) {
    $list = '<ul>';

    foreach ($data as $item) {
        $list .= '<li>';
        $list .= $item['name'];
        if (!empty($item['children'])) {
            $list .= treeList($item['children']);
        }
        $list .= '</li>';
    }

    $list .= '</ul>';

    return $list;
}

$data = array(
    array(
        'name'     => 'Foo',
        'children' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'Bar'
            )
        )
    )
);

echo treeList($data);
```

Comment: There is no ITEM like `$item['children']` in my array.. please take a look at the array dump above

Comment: Well, yeah, obviously I had to go on assumptions when writing this. The example data is just example data, the point is that this is showing much simpler and sane logic how to build the list. You'll need to adapt that to your specific case.

Comment: hi @deceze .. Your answer is not the "Correct" answer of my question.. but it given me hint to make it in a bit easy way.. i used http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiterator.php because my tree structure is a bit complex and then used your function to display the list.. Thank you and god bless you

Comment: You're welcome, glad it put you on the right path, which it was supposed to. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not opeaning the `<li>` tags you are closing it here,
fix this and  try,

```
 else {
        $html .= "</li>\n</ul>\n</li>\n";
        $diff--;
    }
```

Comment: I didn't get what you mean buddy? I am opening the UL above in the function if you see

Comment: you are using </li> before starting it.